# Who were those Russians that the Joker was dancing with in The Killing Joke?

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification, the-killing-joke

In one frame of *The Killing Joke*, the Joker is seen dancing with various people. The two dressed as Russians appear only in this frame, while the others appear throughout the story.

[image: Original]

[image: Deluxe]

Who are these characters, and why do they only appear in this single frame?

Comment: What's wrong with your copy of the comic? Mine doesn't have those acidic colours in that particular scene.

Comment: @Gallifreian - I've had a look a three different versions of the comic (including a scan of the book edition) and all three have the same colour scheme in that scene. I'd be most interested to see an upload of what you've got.

Comment: @Valorum  -  [here](http://imgur.com/a/g7AYj). Mine is a *Deluxe Edition*, I think it's recoloured. And it's also in Russian. Enjoy!

Comment: @Gallifreian - You're not wrong. Same image in English from the HC Full Deluxe addition; https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNHaW.png. Interesting.

Comment: @Valorum  -  I reckon they thought there was enough acidic madness on those pages. Pity, the rainbowy version looks better

Comment: @gallifreian I have the deluxe edition, but this is the only edition I could find online

Comment: Valorum's image is a bit larger, you might want to use it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Russians don't show up at all in the movie.